Is there a way to open a URL on Slack with an automation using Zapier?
I'm trying to develop a ticketing system that allows people on slack to go to the ticket creation URL when typing "create_ticket" or "/create_ticket". I've been using Zapier but haven't been able to figure out the integration path. Is there an efficient way of doing this?
Created slack integration on Zapier, records are not pulling up accordingly. Can't seem to find a way of opening the URL.
